# Android build error com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have to problem when build. i add build firebase core 16.0.0, but when build, this is build firebase core 17.0.0. why it build 17.0.0.I check android 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries, now version 16.0.0, i have to remove build project, but this is not success.
 Can you help me? Thanks.

when i increase version build

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //them multiDexEnabled = true
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // butter knife.
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // gson.
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    // image loading.
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.7.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'

    //com.squareup.retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'

    //com.squareup.okhttp3
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

    //io.reactivex.rxjava2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'

    // keyboard keyboardvisibilityevent
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'

    // Cloud Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    //Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    //Invites and Dynamic Links
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'

    //AdMob
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1' // No trouble in compiling
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    //room Save data in a local database using Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0"

    //push OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3'

    //gmc
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'

    //palette
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'

    //loading
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    //crop image
    implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.7'

    //exoplayer-textureview
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.7.3'

    //facebook .
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'

    //facebook ads
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.1'

    //no name :)
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fix problem : import onesignal

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.10.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue in project.

Answer (score 9):

**First, add build.gradle file, to include the google-services plugin and the Google's Maven repository:**

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services 
plugin
}
}

 allprojects {
// ...
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
 }
```

**add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 // ...
 }

 dependencies {
  // ...
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
  }

  // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**You should also add the dependencies for the Firebase SDKs you want to use. We recommend starting with com.google.firebase:firebase-core**

Answer (score 2):

Remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`
   and use`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'` for firebase database, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue I followed Google firebase integration guidelines and did the following changes in my app/build.gradle and  project/build.gradle

[Follow this link if you have any doubts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

changes in **app/build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
```

Changes in **Project/build.gradle**

```js
repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'// // google-services plugin it should be latest if you are using firebase version 16.0 +
       
    }
    allprojects {
    repositories {
         google()// add it to top instead of bottom or somewhere in middle
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
       
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add google maven repository to your app root build.gradle file

Have a look at doc:
[Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Let me know if it solve your problem

Comment: you want me add line to bottom? . i have add before, but still error// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: There will be root gradle file u have to edit that also according to doc

Comment: You mean :     maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

Comment: That documentation is for version 11.8.0. When updating dependencies to upper versions, it doesn't work, in my case I got a ``Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging`` error, which doesn't appear for lower verions