# Error: could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

today I was trying to update com.google.gms:google-services to 4.2.0 from 4.1.0 as it's the latest version and [recommended](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0) by firebase. But I get this error:

```
Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

And here is my project's build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As Doug Stevenson said the dependency is now up and running so just use google() in your repositories.

If you have any problems with other google repositories (firebase, exoplayer) you can track the issue progress [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30).

Comment: I think there is some issue with `google-services` same question is asked here by different user question links are here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706239/gradle-could-not-find-google-services-jar-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-1-0) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706381/google-play-services-plugin-is-unreachable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704155/could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-0-1/53704698#53704698

Comment: Try this adding this repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704634/752781

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

Comment: This issue is resolved now if you use `google()` in your buildscript dependencies.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because google-services:4.2.0 is not available at Central Repository, so it needs to be downloaded from Android Tools Repository. To add this to your project add

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
```

this to buildscript repositories. For more refer to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services/4.2.0

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        //  Add this to your project 
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when it will be available in Central Repository?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that in Central Repository latest version is 3.11.

Comment: This is only a short term fix.  There is currently something wrong with the Google maven repo.  It's being investigated.  In the long term, you should depend on using `google()` in your build.gradle.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @DougStevenson!

Answer (score 34):

**Monday December 10 2018, 1:30PM PST**

The Google Play services plugin, the Firebase Performance monitoring plug, exoplayer, and possible other dependencies were found to be missing on jCenter.  It's not clear why, but some of the teams are known to be moving their build artifacts to the Google maven repo.

As of right now, the Google Play services plugin has been migrated, and should be available through google() in your buildscript for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hope the problem is fixed as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, good luck with the fix! We are using the bintray one temporarily.

Comment: Is there somewhere we can monitor the status of this?

Answer (score 8):

Try this, work for me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        jcenter {url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'}
        jcenter {url 'https://firebase.bintray.com/gradle'}
        mavenCentral ()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        jcenter {url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'}
        jcenter {url 'https://firebase.bintray.com/gradle'}
        mavenCentral ()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Same code without the line `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` worked for me.

Comment: Also remove `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` from your `build.gradle (Module: app)`

Answer (score 6):

google-services:4.2.0 is now back on google maven repository, just sync gradle with default config:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```