# Maven dependencies for android deleted?

Tags: android, maven, react-native

I am a React Native Developer and I have a problem with the Android world.
As I understand Maven is the repository for the dependencies.

Problem: this morning a dependency is on 404 on `dl.google.com`
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/flexbox/1.0.0/flexbox-1.0.0.jar

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
```

Does anyone know How can I fix this?

[image: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath']

**UPDATE:**

Found that I am not the only one who's having this issue
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/issues/475

It seems to be wider than flexbox... Many dependencies are missing from `google()`, `jCenter()` and `mavenCentral()`.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709146/failed-to-resolve-com-google-androidflexbox1-1-0)

Comment: maven is not a repository but a tool for managing dependencies (it's actually much more than that). It seems the flexbox artifact is not found in the default repos, so you have to add a repo address in your `build.gradle`. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709146/failed-to-resolve-com-google-androidflexbox1-1-0

Comment: everyone is having this today. including me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
All old artifacts are available again on `maven.google.com`

TLDR;
I just delayed my deploy for 2 days

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment106