Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1 Error in Flutter Android Build on CircleCI
I'm facing an issue with my Flutter Android build on CircleCI where it fails with the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:androidDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:prodDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app

Here's the relevant part of my android/app/build.gradle:
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "App Staging", isStaging: true, isProduction: false]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "App", isStaging: false, isProduction: true]
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.11.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1' // added this to implementation
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}

and I've also tried to add a combination on these in android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter() // Note: jcenter is deprecated but can still be used for legacy dependencies
    }
}

Where I've added mavenCentral() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } but nothing works there.
Context:

I am using a Zoom SDK bridge in my Flutter app. (version 5.16.6)
The error occurs during the CircleCI build process but not on local builds.
Running ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies doesn't seem to work.

my CircleCI config:
version: "2.1"
orbs:
  flutter: circleci/flutter@2.0.4
  android: circleci/android@2.5.0
  macos: circleci/macos@2.5.1

parameters:
  manual-staging-run:
    type: boolean
    default: false

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore:
                - staging
                - main
  deploy_staging:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: staging
      - deploy_staging_ios:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
      - deploy_staging_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
  deploy_prod:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
      - deploy_prod_ios:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
      - deploy_prod_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
  manual_deploy_staging:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.manual-staging-run >>
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test
      - deploy_staging_ios:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
      - deploy_staging_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test

commands:
  setup_env:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - flutter/install_sdk_and_pub:
          version: 3.19.5
      - run:
          name: Install Zoom SDK
          command: flutter pub run zoom:unzip_zoom_sdk
  run_fastlane:
    parameters:
      fastlane_lane:
        default: "staging_release"
        type: string
      platform:
        default: ""
        type: string
    steps:
      - run:
          no_output_timeout: 50m
          name: Fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane <<parameters.fastlane_lane>> build_number:$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
          working_directory: <<parameters.platform>>
  build_ios:
    parameters:
      fastlane_lane:
        default: "staging_release"
        type: string
      output_dir:
        default: output
        type: string
    steps:
      - setup_env
      - flutter/install_ios_pod
      - flutter/install_ios_gem:
          cache-version: v1.1
      - run: echo "$APP_STORE_API_KEY_JSON" | base64 --decode > ios/key_file.json
      - run_fastlane:
          fastlane_lane: <<parameters.fastlane_lane>>
          platform: ios
      - store_artifacts:
          path: <<parameters.output_dir>>
          destination: outputs
  build_android:
    parameters:
      flavor:
        default: staging
        type: string
      output_dir:
        default: output
        type: string
    steps:
      - setup_env
      - flutter/install_android_gradle_dependencies
      - flutter/install_android_gem
      - run: echo "$PLAY_STORE_UPLOAD_KEY" | base64 --decode > android/app-keystore
      - run: echo "$PLAY_STORE_UPLOAD_KEY_INFO" | base64 --decode > android/key.properties
      - run: echo "$SUPPLY_JSON_KEY_DATA" > android/play-store-credentials.json
      - run_fastlane:
          fastlane_lane: <<parameters.flavor>>_release
          platform: android
      # - run_fastlane:
      #      fastlane_lane: <<parameters.flavor>>_apk
      #      platform: android
      - store_artifacts:
          path: <<parameters.output_dir>>
          destination: outputs

jobs:
  deploy_staging_android:
    description: Deploy Staging build to internal testers in Play Store
    executor:
      name: android/android-machine
      tag: 2024.01.1
    steps:
      - build_android:
          flavor: staging
          output_dir: android/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-staging-release.apk

  deploy_prod_android:
    description: Deploy Prod build to internal testers in Play Store
    executor:
      name: android/android-machine
      tag: 2024.01.1
    steps:
      - build_android:
          flavor: prod
          output_dir: android/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-prod-release.apk

  deploy_staging_ios:
    description: Deploy Staging build to TestFlight
    macos:
      xcode: 15.3.0
    resource_class: macos.m1.medium.gen1
    environment:
      HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE: 1
    steps:
      - run: brew install graphicsmagick
      - run:
          command: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            if [ "$(uname -m)" = "arm64" ]; then
                /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
            else
                echo "Rosetta 2 can only be installed on Apple Silicon!"
                exit 1
            fi
          name: Installing Rosetta 2

      - build_ios:
          fastlane_lane: staging_release

  deploy_prod_ios:
    description: Deploy Prod build to TestFlight
    macos:
      xcode: 15.3.0
    resource_class: macos.m1.medium.gen1
    steps:
      - run:
          command: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            if [ "$(uname -m)" = "arm64" ]; then
                /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
            else
                echo "Rosetta 2 can only be installed on Apple Silicon!"
                exit 1
            fi
      - build_ios:
          fastlane_lane: pre_release

  lint_and_test:
    description: Run flutter analyze and Unit Tests
    docker:
      - image: "ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:3.19.5"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - flutter/install_pub
      - run: echo 'export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: Install junitreport
          shell: "/bin/bash --login -eo pipefail"
          command: dart pub global activate junitreport
      - run: mkdir test-results
      - run:
          name: Run flutter analysis
          command: flutter analyze
      - run:
          name: Run Unit Test
          command: flutter test --machine | tojunit -o test-results/unit-test-report.xml
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results

How can I resolve the Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1 error in my CircleCI build process? Are there any additional steps I should take to ensure that the dependencies are correctly resolved in the CI environment?

Did you try check the library existence using maven central? Looks like an issue with the sdk version available for download. As per maven central repo only 3.0.0 version is available. This might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709146/failed-to-resolve-com-google-androidflexbox1-1-0

For some reason it's been removed from maven https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.pom (now returning 404). Probably a temporary situation?

I was able to resolve it. For anyone who's facing this issue, it was because my other package included implementation com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1 under dependencies. I removed that and added mavenCentral to it, then it started working.

Yes! Its solved here too! Thanks @nyphur!
