# Bitrise error Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, bitrise

I get the following error in bitrise CI, although the build works find locally. I made no changes to the gradle files yet they suddenly stopper working in bitrise CI

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'src'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         https://maven.google.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://maven.google.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

but `./gradlew assembleDebug` it works fine locally.

gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
        maven { url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository" }
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**com.google.gms.google-services** just disappears from google repository (at https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)

Issue here => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

A temporary workaround is to add this repository to your buildscript repositories

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53709401/5420747). Google Seems to be having some issues; they are currently looking into it.

The reason it works locally is because your dependancy is still cached. If you need to fix it ***temporarily***, add the following line to your `buildscript` --> `repositories` in your main (project-level) `build.gradle` file. (See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707633/5420747))

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
```