# What happened to the google-services plugin?

Tags: android, maven

The google-services plugin currently is not resolving in my project.  I get the error:

```
 What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project ''.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.2/google-services-4.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

When I browse the google maven repo here: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

the google-services library is just missing.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be temporarily unavailable or is being moved somewhere. My Flutter project fails with the same error :(

Comment: Looks like it's already been reported, and there's a workaround for now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

Comment: the question already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706565/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-2-0