# Error:Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Not able to build the code getting error.

```
CONFIGURE FAILED in 5s
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.jar
    https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.pom
    https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.5/firebase-plugins-1.1.5.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

After lot of googling did not find any working solution.

top level gradle file 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
already added.

google(),jcentre repository added in build.gradle file.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire, minimal build.gradle configurations that reproduce this problem.

Comment: This sounds related to (but not exactly the same as) the issue with the Google Play services plugin.  Recent versions of the build artifact have gone missing from jCenter.  It's being looked into.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706565/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-2-0/

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue this morning and I resolved adding the following to the repositories block of my project:

```
jcenter {url 'https://firebase.bintray.com/gradle'}
```

Comment: This seems like the current workaround. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

Answer (score 1):

It seems another case where the artifact gone missing. I found there is another artifact called `com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.1.5` and use it instead of `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5` to make my build works again. But somehow this is not documented anywhere so i am not sure whether this is intended name changes or not.