# Is com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1 missing from google official maven repository? I'm unable to build flutter+firebase

Tags: android, maven, firebase, gradle, flutter

I've followed [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) to setup a working firebase+flutter project: 
The problem comes when gradle tries to fetch the dependency `com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1` for the android build.
Apparently version `3.2.1` is currently missing from google's maven repository, it is available on other repositories as visible [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services/3.2.1) , but the official google repository lacks this version as visible from my build output:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.pom
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.1/google-services-3.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

I'm totally new to both gradle and android, so I'm not aware of any risk involved using one of the other repositories linked above (bintray,spring plugins) and I hadn't any luck in finding such answers. If I wanna use google's official repository I have to downgrade to the version `3.1.0`, but the official firebase guide explicitly states that firebase is compatible with google services `3.2.1`, so I don't feel comfortable downgrading because I wouldn't want to deal with weird problems caused by version incompatibility.

Comment: 4.2.0 is the latest version at this moment.  Any reason not to use that instead?

Comment: as stated above, the guide linked explicitly tells to adopt version 3.2.1, anyway 4.2.0 is missing as well so even if I wanted to, it's not possible to install it and try

Comment: just for clarity, I can install only versions 3.1.0 and 3.1.1, nothing above this version is available.

Comment: Im getting the problems too and so are others by the looks of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704155/could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-0-1

Comment: There are currently a lot of errors like this with every version of the plugin.  It's being investigated.