A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. google service 4.4.2
can anyone suggest how to fix this error in flutter
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1:.
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
any suggestion how to solve this problem

This will solve the issue

this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704634/4373661

Could you let me know what you did first before encountering that error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have so much trouble in new versions. So I use old ide versions. But old ides is also work with android 35. With this configuration i am able to build my application with google play services. This might work you too.
build.gradle(android)
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'
    }
}

plugins{
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version '4.4.2' apply false
    id ("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version '3.0.2' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

build.gradle(module:app)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android{
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2"))
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics')
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics')
}

settings.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
}

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

And my android ide is;
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 13
Build #AI-232.10203.10.2321.11075088, built on November 9, 2023
